# Red5Pro: Server keeps loading without response

Tags: red5, red5pro, red5-recorder, red5-hls-plugin

I have set-up Red5Pro on my Linux machine by following this [tutorial](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/installation/ubuntuinstall/) and everything seems to be working fine:

[image]

But, the page keeps loading without getting any response:
[image]
And this is what I have in the bottom of the browser:
[image]
I've checked the console and nothing is being logged there.
Any idea why is this happening?

---

**NOTE:** It takes a while for these messages to be logged which is a bit strange:
[image]

---

The JAVA version is 9:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently Red5 Pro must be run with JDK 8.

If you are running on Ubuntu 16, run

apt-get install -y default-jre unzip libva1 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libvdpau1 jsvc ntp
If you are running on Ubuntu 18, run

apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless unzip libva2 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libvdpau1 jsvc ntp
As of this post, Red5 Pro is not supported on Ubuntu 19 or 20.

If you continue to have issues, you should open a ticket via https://red5pro.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new.

Comment: I have Linux Mint 18.2

Comment: I installed java 8. Now, when I run java -version, I get this (openjdk version "1.8.0_282"). And when I run javac -version, I get this:  (javac 1.8.0_282)